# Autorestart not working for supervisord programs

Tags: python, supervisord

I am working with supervisord and I am facing issues in automatic restart of supervisord programs.

### `supervisord.conf`

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/dev/null
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid
nodaemon=true

[unix_http_server]
file = /tmp/supervisor.sock

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[program:worker]
command=./manage.py rq worker %(ENV_QUEUES)s
process_name=%(program_name)s-%(process_num)s
numprocs=%(ENV_WORKERS_COUNT)s
directory=/app
stopsignal=TERM
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=300
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[eventlistener:worker_healthcheck]
autorestart=true
serverurl=AUTO
command=./manage.py rq healthcheck
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
events=TICK_60
```

### Supervisorctl Status

```
abc@abc-adhocworker-c89d9667b-9lqbd:/app$ exec supervisorctl -c worker.conf status

worker:worker-0                  FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)

worker:worker-1                  FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)

worker_healthcheck               RUNNING   pid 14, uptime 7:43:34
```

Status shows they are in fatal state but not recovering automatically even I've configured `autorestart=true`.

### What else do i need to make sure automatic recovery/restart of programs in case of errors ?

Is it possible that restart is relying on healthcheck `eventlistener` and it might be sending false signal i.e. everything is good and thus automatic restart not working for programs ?

My supervisord.conf doesn't have supervisorctl section so not sure if it is added then it can trigger auto restart correctly as without that `supervisorctl status` might be failing for supervisord programs ?